# How to check repeatedly whether a music player is active?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-audiomanager

I want to check whether a music is playing using my application. I have done with my application and it works only for once. But I want know how can we repeatedly check for this.

This is my code. But this code just checks whether music is active or not only once.

```
if(mAudioManager.isMusicActive()) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Audio is playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent srvc = new Intent(this, OverlayShowingService.class);
        startService(srvc);     
        try {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.wait(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Exception found");
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Might be an idea to format your question with a bit more information about **what you've tried** and **what you're having an issue with**. Also, please don't randomly CAPITALISE words, we're not deaf.

Comment: OK @scottmcgready, I have changed as you told.

Answer (score 0):

**as told by  ScottMcGready please follow his suggestopns**

Here is answer for your question-

```
//Declare the timer
Timer t = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

          //here you can set check of players active ness

        //Called each time when 2000 milliseconds (2 second)
    }

},
//Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
0,
//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
1000);
```

and if you wanted to cancel the task simply call t.cancle()

Comment: Thank you so so much @sud. Can I implement it using a Broadcast receiver?